# como eu faço para remover alguns números depois da virgula em PHP

Tags: php, variáveis, operadores, conversão, decimal

como eu faço para remover alguns números depois da virgula em PHP?
ex: 25.52382832732732...
 ai eu quero que fique somente 25.52

Comment: E se fosse 25.52832832732732...  qual seria o retorno esperado?

Comment: Leo Caracciolo no caso eu queria o retorno de no máximo dois números depois da vírgula, mas ja consegui fazer usando a função (round).

Comment: Eu sei, estou perguntado se o numero fosse 25.52832832732732.. o retorno desejado seria 25.52  ou 25,53 ou seja, considerar o arredondamento ou não?

Comment: bom pensando bem isso seria um problema em outro caso sim, porém nos critérios que estou usando não irá fazer diferença se for 25.52 ou 25.53 então não precisa considerar esse arredondamento.

Comment: se não precisa considerar arredondamento faça assim echo floor(25.52832832732732*100)/100; ira retornar 25.52

Comment: ok isto tambem funcionou mas qual a diferença? usei o round($var, 2) e deu o mesmo resultado.

Comment: observe bem que os numeros são diferentes, 25.5238.... e 25.5283.... (38 e 83). Se fizer round(25.52832832732732, 2)  vai retornar 25,53 e não 25,52

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta seria uma solução

Você utiliza a função `round` que no primeiro parâmetro recebe o numero e no segundo recebe o número opcional de dígitos decimais para arredondar sendo que o padrão é 0

```
$valor = round(25.52382832732732, 2);
echo $valor;
```

[fonte](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php)

Comment: Valeu Amadeu Antunes, estou arressem começando com PHP, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é com o `number_format`, desta meneira:

```
number_format($valor, 2);
```